# How To Create A Report in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to create a report in Magento. I followed the tutorial from Alan Storm on getting things started in the admin panel http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers and I now have a grasp of how to get the controllers working in the admin panel.

I would like to take this to the next step and create reports. The reports that I am creating I think I just want them to work like the grid widgets that are used throughout the entire Magento admin panel.

However, I am hard pressed to find a good tutorial on how to create these. If someone could explain how these work or point me towards a tutorial that worked for them, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*** UPDATE ***

An SQL based approach, to consider:

- https://github.com/kalenjordan/custom-reports

---

Personally I've tried implementing Reports the "Magento" way and found its much easier and simpler to just use the Grid instead.  However here are some of the bookmarks I have in regards to building out reports.

- http://codegento.com/2011/03/creating-custom-magento-reports/

Hope these help, I have to admit the way the way you build reports in Magento is very screwy, at least to me the approach seems very backwards.

Comment: Between these two I was able to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @BOOMER, do you usually just query like for example order models directly when you do reports using a simple grid?  I know it's probably safer to query an index rather than the order table directly, but not sure how big of a risk it would be really.  In terms of like potentially locking up SQL tables an impacting end user checkouts for example.

Comment: @sparcksoft I would say stick with using the models directly and avoid any direct queries, if possible of course.